# How to suspend a running thread using win32 api's?

Tags: multithreading, winapi

Here it is

1. Create a thread in suspended state.

   ```
   hThrd1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) ThreadProc1, (LPVOID)
   &obj1, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &dwFirstThreadID);
   ```
2. Resume the thread whenever required

   ```
   ResumeThread(hThrd1);
   ```

How do I suspend this running thread. I may resume it after sometime, but I want to suspend it now.

I called

```
    SuspendThread(hThrd1);
```

Still the for loop in the ThreadProc keeps running. Now how do I avoid it? Also suggest me for any alternatives.

Comment: Did the Suspend function succeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the problem. Initially thread HANDLE hThrd1 was declared inside WndProc. Since WndProc is being called again & again, the HANDLE that I got during CreateThread was not the same that was passed to suspend thread. (It was an embarrassing mistake)

Now I have declared it globally. This solves the problem and works as intended.